# Laravel query builder or Eloquent both return null result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to return a single id from a query result. When I dump the query using the `\DB::getQueryLog()`, it shows the correct query. And when I plug the query into my DB manager, it returns the exact result I want.

I have tried the following two different approaches and both return null each time.

```
$drawings = DrawingsModel::query()
    ->select('id')
    ->from('drawings')
    ->where('draw_date', '=', $this->pc->options['start_date'])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

dump(DB::getQueryLog());
dd($drawings);
```

Also tried this;

```
$drawings = \DB::query()
     ->select('id')
     ->from('drawings')
     ->where('game_id', '=', $game->id)
     ->where('draw_date', '=', $this->pc->options['start_date'])
     ->first();

dump(DB::getQueryLog());
dd($drawings);
```

This is the result of the getQueryLog();

```
1 => array:3 [
  "query" => "select `id` from `drawings` where `game_id` = ? and 
  `draw_date` = ? limit 1"
  "bindings" => array:2 [
     0 => 1
     1 => "2023-08-15"
  ]
  "time" => 3.91
]
```

Regardless of what method I try though, I always get null as my result. I feel like I have to be overlooking something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might need to debug the value of `$game->id` and `$this->pc->options['start_date']` at the time of execution and verifying personally that both of those exist in 1 field in the database. Don't rely on code or the fact that you pressed the right buttons.

Comment: Have to ask about the `draw_date` ... is this literally only a `date` data type, and not a `datetime` data type? If it is `datetime`, the query will never match a date like `2023-08-15 00:00:00`, or whatever the time value may be if the time portion is present.

Comment: @ezw - Yeah, have already done that and confirmed that I am getting the values needed for each binding. Also showing that in the origin post as a dumped the query log. So, yeah, everything is as expected.

Comment: @PaulT. - Yeah...DDL of that table is date and not datetime.

Comment: have you tried running raw query in SQL editor? if yes, then did you get the desired result from it?

Comment: @MitKathrotia - Yeah, I took the dumped query and replaced the binding placeholders with the 
values from the query log dump and it works exactly as I desire. So, this is why I am so baffled by this null result.

Comment: I even tried running the query in tinker the way it is built and even that worked exactly as desired. So, WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of digging, it turns out that putting where conditions in an array worked for solving my issue. The fix was as simple as replacing this;

```
->where('game_id', '=', $game->id)
->where('draw_date', '=', $this->pc->options['start_date'])->get();
```

with this;

```
->where(['game_id', '=', $game_id],['draw_date', '=', $start_date])->get();
```